# Returning a closing tag and a starting tag in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Is there any way to have a component of the form:

```
function Break(){
  return <React.Fragment></div><div className="section"></React.Fragment>;
}
```

Basically i'm trying to have it so that whenever  component is displayed, it closes a

```
<div className="section>
```

and starts another

```
<div className="section">
```

Comment: nope. it doesn't make sense in the context of a react component. why do you think you want this?

Comment: remember that jsx actually compiles to normal function calls. there's no such thing as "opening" and "closing" when calling `React.createElement` just `element type`, `props` and `children`

Comment: @azium basically in a JSON i'll be receiving, i'll be getting an array of layout elements, to be rendered. Among them is a "break" element which will signify the end of a section and beginning of a section. I figured i would wrap the elements to be rendered in the div with className "section" and close them and open it again accordingly whenever "Break" shows up.

Comment: hard to say what you really need. sounds like wrapping sections normally then rendering a `<br />` or `<hr />` where the break element is

Comment: No, you can't. You'll have to embed the whole component, means once you open a tag, you'll have to close it.

Comment: I have same problem. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you are trying to render a specific no. of items (sections) from some kind of list or rows per parent element.
This can be a `<div className="parent"></div>` for example. So that the result is:

```
<div>
<div className="parent">
    <div className="section></div>
    <div className="section></div>
    <div className="section></div>
</div>

<div className="parent">
    <div className="section></div>
    <div className="section></div>
    <div className="section></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Let's assume you have an array of numbers `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` you want to render inside

`<div className="section></div>`

e.g.

```
<div className="section>1</div>
<div className="section>2</div>
```

and so on.

You can create chunks of the array based on how many `<div className="section></div>` items you want to render per `<div className="parent">`
let's assume you want 3 `<div className="section></div>` per `<div className="parent">` as in the code above.
You can use lodash's `chunk()` method to do this.
https://lodash.com/docs#chunk

```
parents = lodash.chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
//parents is [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

think of each inner array as a parent element and the items inside each parent element as section elements.

therefore in react it would be rendered like:

```
render() {
   const parents = lodash.chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
   return (
    <div>
     {
       parents.map((parent) => (
         <div className="parent">
         {
           parent.map((section) => (
             <div className="section">{ section }</div>
           ))
         }
         </div>
       ))
     }
    </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> basically in a JSON i'll be receiving, i'll be getting an array of
>   layout elements, to be rendered. Among them is a "break" element which
>   will signify the end of a section and beginning of a section. I
>   figured i would wrap the elements to be rendered in the div with
>   className "section" and close them and open it again accordingly
>   whenever "Break" shows up

Although what you asked for originally is not possible, I have a solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

What you can do is `split` your array using the "break" element as your delimiter. Then `map` each set of elements that were split and wrap them in a `<section>` element. You can then pass that array to your `return` statement inside `render`.

```
render(){
  const allElems = JSON.parse(jsonArray)
                       .toString()
                       .split('breakElem')
                       .map(setOfElem => <section>{setOfElem.split(',')}</section>)
  return <div>{allElems}</div>
}
```

This code has not been tested but hopefully this can help you accomplish what you are looking to achieve.